# Is it possible to give alias name to ip address with port number in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, alias, ip-address

I have one question regarding given alias to ip address with port number.

For example I am executing jenkins in my local system in port number 8080 and nexus in port number 8081.

I will accessing GUI by typing address manually as below.

For jenkins: `192.168.122.1:8080`
For Nexus: `192.168.122.1:8081`

Instead of following above process it is possible to alias names as below.

`192.168.122.1:8080` -> `jenkins.world`
`192.168.122.1:8081` -> `nexus.world`

or alias as below.

`192.168.122.1:8080` -> `go/jenkins`
`192.168.122.1:8081` -> `go/nexus`

Can you please check and advice about the feasibility of above type of alias in CentOS 7.6 OS.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few options but I don't think you'll be able to achieve exactly what your looking for.

If you added into your /etc/hosts to include

```
192.168.122.1  jenkins.world nexus.world
```

Then in your browser you could go to jenkins.world:8080 or nexus.world:8081 , noting that you would have to include/switch the port number as it cannot be placed in hosts file.

If you you don't mind launching the browser from your terminal you could add a line similiar to this in your .bashrc file in your home directory.

```
alias jenkins.world="firefox 192.168.122.1:8080"
alias nexus.world="firefox 192.168.122.1:8081"
```

Another alternative is the good ol fashioned browser bookmarks

Or if your knowledgeable with web servers have a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997071/redirecting-from-port-80-to-different-ports-based-on-url